# how to use queryrunner to deal with multiple filters with mysql sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot

Suppose I have a mysql table as follows:

| id | sex | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | male | 18 |
| 2 | female | 27 |
| 3 | female | 19 |
| 4 | male | 34 |

Then I have a html page that can query the results with multiple fiters.

```
<form>
    <label for="sex">sex</label>
    <select id="sex" name="sex">
        <option value="all">all</option>
        <option value="male">male</option>
        <option value="female">female</option>
    </select>
    <label for="age">age</label>
    <select id="age" name="age">
        <option value="-1">all</option>
        <option value="under18"><18</option>
        <option value="18to35">18-35</option>
        <option value="over35">>35</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="query">
</form>
```

so we can see that, if we select sex with male and age <18，then I can use sql as follows

```
select * from table where sex=? and age=?
```

when I use queryrunner, I can do as follows:

```
String sql = "select * from table where sex=? and age=?";
Object[] params = {input_sex, input_age}
List<User> results = queryrunner.query(sql, resultBean, params)
```

But, if input sex is all and age is all, then the sql used above can not finish the task. If I have many filters, I have to check every filter. So is there any method to deal with "all"?

Comment: there is no universal number, so you need to build your query depending on which are not all, and don't add the rest

Answer (score 0):

There are tricks like this:

```
select * from table 
where sex=IFNULL(NULLIF(?, 'all'), sex) 
and age=IFNULL(NULLIF(?, 'all'), age)
```

But it's not worth it, because it spoils the use of indexes, and it results in code that takes 30 minutes to explain to any developer reading it.

It's better to write some code in your application that adds terms to your SQL query string conditionally.

Comment: I'm not going to explain the trick I show above. Read the manual entries for the NULLIF() and IFNULL() functions if you're curious.